# How can i use a dynamic path variables to mapping static file?

Tags: java, spring-boot

my code like this, ues a static resource mapping

```java
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/scene/template/{id}/file/**").addResourceLocations("file:" +"upload/**");
    }
```

i want to use http://localhost:8890/scene/template/1/file/frame.js to visit the file

how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it something like this?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ResourceConfigs implements WebMvcConfigurer {



        private static final String[] CLASS_PATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
                 "file:///home/akhil/Downloads/scene/template/"
        };
    
    
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/scene/template/**")
                    .addResourceLocations(CLASS_PATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS)
                    .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache().cachePrivate())
                    .resourceChain(true)
                    .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
        }
    
    }
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Welcome ,  you can approve the answer since others might find it useful as well.